# Fitting a linear combination of distributions

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, distribution, curve-fitting

I have 5 arrays  (columns of a pandas data frame)
and I want calculate the best fit for a linear combination of the distributions to an exponential distribution.
for example:

```
a*(d1)+b*(d2)+c*(d3)+d*(d4)+e*(d5)=Y
```

where Y has an exponential distribution (which i know) and a,b,c,d,e are the coefficients to fit.

I tried using curve_fit or lmfit python libraries but didn't get how to do it effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a linear model. Use the package [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = df[['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5']]
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y)
reg.get_params()
```